# How can I download a XML #document generated by DOMparser?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

Good morning.

I have a webpage with a form that generates a XML Document with DOMparser().
That's the function to get the XML:

```
function textToXML(text) {
    try {
        var xml = null;

        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            xml = parser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
            var found = xml.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
            if (!found || !found.length || !found[0].childNodes.length) {
                return xml;
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml.async = false;
            xml.loadXML(text);
            return xml;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // suppress
    }
}
```

And I get a XML document like (displayed on console.log()):
[image: XML document obtained (pixelated to don't show data)]

And I don't know how could I download it now, I have tried with

```
location.href='data:application/download,' + encodeURIComponent(xmlFile)
```

but the downloaded file just show something like "[object] Object".

Comment: In IE>=9 you can use [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I GOT IT. Finally I was searching for a plugin and I got this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js !! I hope it help somebody more than me! Thanks for try to help me!